# How to use socks proxy via CLI without proxychains (to install proxychains)

Tags: bash

I am unable to install proxychains on a remote system because the system only has outbound access to port 22/tcp to my server. However, I can use `ssh -D 9050 root@myip` to listen on port `9050` for socks proxy.

That being said, how can I run `apt update` and `apt install proxychains` through socks port 9050 so that I *can* install proxychains and use it for future commands?

I've tried to run:

`export http_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 https_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050`

but as soon as I ran `apt update`, the outbound connection fails. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it or if I'm just missing something small.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I was able to use is by downloading the ZIP version of https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng, SCP'ing it over to the remote server, and then compiling it locally on that system.

Afterwards, I'm able to use `./proxychains4g -f src/proxychains.conf <command>` and so now it looks like I'm good to go.